# Declaracion de metodos en JFrame (Eclipse)

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

quiero declarar un metodo dentro del constructor de Jframe para usarlo mas arriba pero no importa donde lo coloque, me marcan errores (illegal modifier, void[] is an invalide type, syntax error) . Alguien sabe como solucionarlo y porque sucede?

```
    public VentanaJuego() {
         setTitle("TateTi");
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setBounds(100, 100, 574, 423);
         this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//aparece en el medio
         public void prueba() {
             System.out.println("probando");
    }
    posicionesTablero[0]=posicion1;//son tipo matriz
    posicionesTablero[1]=posicion2;
    posicionesTablero[2]=posicion3;
    posicionesTablero[3]=posicion4;
    posicionesTablero[4]=posicion5;
    posicionesTablero[5]=posicion6;
    posicionesTablero[6]=posicion7;
    posicionesTablero[7]=posicion8;
    posicionesTablero[8]=posicion9;
    
    public void seleccionar(int posicion) {
        if(posicionesTablero[posicion].getText().isEmpty()) {
            if(opcionX.isSelected()) {
                posicionesTablero[posicion].setText("X");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacerlo así? Realmente no se puede, puedes conseguir algo similar con lambdas (Java >= 8), pero ¿cuál es el caso?.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás enfrentando se debe a que estás intentando declarar métodos dentro del constructor de la clase VentanaJuego. En Java, no es posible declarar métodos dentro de otro método, incluido el constructor.

Para solucionar esto, debes declarar tus métodos fuera del constructor, como miembros de la clase. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo

```
public class VentanaJuego extends JFrame {
    private JButton[] posicionesTablero;

    public VentanaJuego() {
        setTitle("TateTi");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 574, 423);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Inicializar la matriz posicionesTablero
        posicionesTablero = new JButton[9];
        // Código para inicializar cada elemento del arreglo posicionesTablero

        prueba(); // Llamar al método prueba()

        seleccionar(0); // Llamar al método seleccionar() con un argumento de ejemplo
    }

    public void prueba() {
        System.out.println("Probando");
    }

    public void seleccionar(int posicion) {
        if (posicionesTablero[posicion].getText().isEmpty()) {
            if (opcionX.isSelected()) {
                posicionesTablero[posicion].setText("X");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, se declaran los métodos prueba() y seleccionar(int posicion) fuera del constructor, como miembros de la clase VentanaJuego. También se crea e inicializa la matriz posicionesTablero dentro del constructor.

Recuerda que los métodos deben declararse dentro del cuerpo de la clase, pero fuera de cualquier otro método, incluido el constructor.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".

Comment: Hola David, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y explicacion! Ya pude solucionar mi problema